# Выдается ошибка Rate limit reached в песочнице VK Dev

Tags: vkontakte-api

На сайте https://vk.com/dev/messages.send есть песочница, где можно вызвать метод `messages.send`. При его отправке возвращается ответ

```
{
    "error": {
     "error_code": 29,
     "error_msg": "Rate limit reached",
     ...
```

При этом сегодня ни разу не использовал на своем аккаунте какие либо методы VK API.